# Pointwise convergence in two variables.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm not sure about the following (taken from a proof).
If $x \rightarrow x_0$ and $r\rightarrow r_0$
then $\chi_B(r,x) \rightarrow \chi_B(r_0,x_0)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n - S(r_o, x_o)$, 
where $S(r,x) = \{y : |y-x| ) =r\}$. Where
$B(r,x)$ is the ball around $x$ with radius r and $\chi$ is the indicator function. 
Why is it like this?
Can anyone come up with a sequence where this is not true on the boundary $S(r,x)$?
Can I just take a sequence that is inside the set all the time converging to the boundary ?

Comment: Can you explain what is $B$ and ${χ_B}(r,x)$.

Comment: Sure done it now.

Comment: I still don't get it. $B$ is clear but you have two arguments $r$ and $x$ in the characteristic function, whereas usually there is one. Or do you mean the open interval $(r,x)$? Then the notation should be $χ_B((r,x))$.

Comment: Note that the function $\chi_B(r,x)$ is not continuous on the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

For $x \ in \Bbb{R}^n \setminus S(r_0, x_0)$ there are two cases:

1. $|x - x_0| < r_0$, i.e. $\chi_{B(x_0, r_0)}(x) =1$. By continuity, we get $|x_n - x|<r_n$ for $n$ large enough (why?), i.e. $\chi_{B(r_n, x_n)}(x) = 1$ for such $n$.
2. $|x - x_0| > r_0$, i.e. $\chi_{B(x_0, r_0)}(x)= 0$. By continuity, we get $|x_n - x|>r_n$ for $n$ large enough (why?), i.e. $\chi_{B(r_n, x_n)}(x) = 0$ for such $n$.

The above shows the claim.

For a counter example for the convergence on the boundary, consider $x_n = x_0 = 0$, $r_n = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ and $r_0 = 1$. This is basically what was already hinted in the comments.